# VolumeUnit conversion from quarts to cups seems off

Tags: swift, foundation, measurement

I'm working on some Swift code that is intended to supply multipliers for conversions between some common volume units. Unless I'm using it incorrectly, I seems to have found an anomaly in conversions from quarts to cups.

Here's a simple unit test I wrote to demonstrate the problem I'm running into:

```swift
func testUnitConversions() throws {
    let quarts = Measurement(value: 1, unit: UnitVolume.quarts)
    let conversion = quarts.converted(to: UnitVolume.cups)
    let value = conversion.value
    XCTAssertEqual(value, 4)
}
```

In Xcode 15.3 it fails with:

> "testUnitConversions(): XCTAssertEqual failed: ("3.9431375") is not equal to ("4.0")"

Every conversion site I look at on the web tells me that a quart equals 4 cups. Am I doing this conversion incorrectly or is it a Swift issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 US cup = 1/4 quart but 1 US cup = 0.98578432 US legal cup and 4 * a legal cup is 3,94313728 so it looks like what `Measurement` uses for `UnitVolume.cups` is a US Legal Cup

Comment: Looking at the conversion table to litres in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/unitvolume), this indeed seems to be the case. 1qt is 0.946353L, but 1c is 0.24L.